# Change content of <span> with :hover and :hover:after

Tags: html, css, hover

This code works fine:

HTML:

```
<span class="counter" >test</span>
```

CSS:

```
  .counter:hover:after{
    content: "hello";
  }
```

Result:
`testhello`

But how can I just transform 'test' to 'hello'. I try the code below but nothing append:

CSS:

```
  .counter:hover{
    content: "goodbye";
  }
```

Expected result:
`goodbye`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content` can only be used in conjunction with `::before` and `::after`. `content` is not the text inside an element. You should use it this way:

```css
.counter:after {
  content: "hello";
}

.counter:hover::after {
  content: "goodbye";
}
```

```html
<span class="counter" ></span>
```

Javascript solution:

```js
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");

counter.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  this.innerHTML = "hello";
})
counter.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  this.innerHTML = "goodbye";
})
```

```html
<span class="counter" >test</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like a tips for change a content already present. May be in JavaScript with mouseover, but I have the same problem :/

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER I added a js solution. What is the expected output exactly?

Comment: Thanks, It works, but a last detail. I would like the <span> come back at "test" when you aren't hover. Do you know a function ? Like may be `queryUnSelector` ?

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER I edited second snippet. like this? I can't understand exactly.

Comment: @HippolyteBRINGER are you really sure you want to use JS for such simple thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use font-size to hide the old content and show the new one:

```css
.counter:hover:after {
  content: "hello";
  font-size:initial;
}

.counter:hover {
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<span class="counter">test</span>
```